# Node.js export behaves differently from ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

In ES6 modules, this works as expected:

- index.js

```js
import { foo, init } from "./foo";

init();
console.log(foo);  // 42
```

- foo.js

```js
export let foo;
export const init = () => {
  foo = 42;
};
```

---

However in Node.js, when I tried the same thing, the `foo` didn't get updated.

How can I make the `foo` updates to `42` after `init()` is run?

- index.js

```js
let { foo, init } = require('./foo');

init();
console.log(foo);  // undefined
```

- foo.js

```js
let foo;

const init = () => {
    foo = 42;
};

module.exports = {
    init,
    foo
};
```

I know I could export a function `getFoo()` and returns the updated `foo`, but it seems not very convenient.

What's the proper way to export a variable in Node.js that may change after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior here, which you can see in ES6 modules:

```
console.log(foo);  // undefined
init();
console.log(foo);  // 42
```

should feel pretty odd in comparison to how JS normally works - `foo` *appears* to be a local identifier, but if it happens to be an import from another module, if the other module's export changes, the `foo` binding wherever it's imported will change as well.

Without using ES6 modules, there is no (reasonable) way to replicate that sort of behavior using a single identifier.

You *can* use ES6 modules in Node if you want, though. Use the original code with the ES6 module syntax, and then run:

```
node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

Build systems like Webpack can also transpile code written in ES6 modules into vanilla JS, though such transpiled code ends up turning the imports into a namespace object. Eg, this:

```
import { foo, init } from "./foo";

init();
console.log(foo);  // 42
```

will turn into something like

```
const fooNamespace = __webpack_require__("./foo.js");
fooNamespace.init();
console.log(fooNamespace.foo);
```

It's just like if you had a reference to an object which, when a function inside it is called, mutates the object. You could implement this if you wanted.

```
const obj = {
  foo: undefined,
  init() { obj.foo = 42 }
};
module.exports = obj;
```

---

Although one *can* use ES6 modules to make imported identifiers seemingly reassign themselves on their own, keep in mind that, since such code is potentially confusing, some prefer to [avoid such](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-mutable-exports.md) [patterns entirely](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--no-mutable-exports).